# Relative percentage height not showing properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to tweak the graph so that the highest bar will always be at 100%
However, there seems to be a slight padding which causes the graph to actually be a few percent lesser than what it ought to be.

Here's what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/MrDhG/

What I have tried to do is add the following to the y-axis:

```
y-axis: 
...
endOnTick: false,
maxPadding: 0,
...
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/MrDhG/1/

However, this sets the bars to go over and beyond the 100%.
This is fine if, for example, the graph was from 0-150% and it stopped at 100%, but currently its behavior is slightly unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get max version, and use tickPositioner to calculate intervals.

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/MrDhG/12/

```
tickPositioner:function(){

            var min = 0,
                tick = 0,
                positions = [],
                increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

            for (min; tick<= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
            return positions;                 

        },
```

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick. I didn't know about tickPositioner.